# 30-second interval between cells in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been trying for a few days to run a query in PostgreeSQL where I need to collect the following data: "Machine ID, Timestamp, Capsule ID".
Each row has an index (primary key) and corresponds to a request, I have to get a list of machines from country X that make at least 2 coffees in less than half a minute.
I can't calculate the time difference between one row and another. For example

```
 index        machineID           TimeStamp            Capsule ID
    1               A1            2021-08-02 14:18:00         6
    2               A1            2021-08-02 14:18:25         6
    3               A1            2021-08-02 14:18:31         6
```

I need to show only index 1 and 2 because they are within the 30 second interval but I can't do it.

I'm trying with this code

```
select brand.consumption.index, brand.consumption.recipeid, brand.consumption.machineid,  brand.consumption.rcv_timestamp, brand.consumption.volume_brewed, brand.recipecode_list.cupsizeid, brand.consumption.capsule_productid

from brand.consumption, brand.recipecode_list

where brand.consumption.recipeid = brand.recipecode_list.recipeid
and brand.consumption.capsule_productid = brand.recipecode_list.productid
and brand.consumption.capsule_recipetypeid = brand.recipecode_list.recipetype
and brand.consumption.index 
in 
(SELECT distinct tt1
  
FROM (
SELECT t1.index tt1,
               t2.index tt2,
               t1.machineid,
               (t2.utc_timestamp - t1.utc_timestamp) * (60 * 60 * 24)  result 
          
FROM brand.consumption t1
          
LEFT JOIN brand.consumption t2
           
ON (t1.machineid = t2.machineid)
         
where t2.rcv_timestamp >= sysdate -2) t1

where tt1 != tt2 and result between -30 and  30)

and brand.consumption.countryid = 'X'

order by brand.consumption.machineid, brand.consumption.utc_timestamp
```

I have a database in which there are several machines that produce coffee, and I have to filter which of these machines in country X produced more than 2 coffees in less than 30 sec.
For example:

```
Machine A 
ID 1 - coffee at 19:00:00 
ID 2 - coffee at 19:00:05
ID 3 - coffee at 19:00:18 
ID 4 - coffee at 19:00:28 
ID 5 - coffee at 19:00:31 

Machine B 
ID 6 - coffee at 19:00:08 
ID 7 - coffee at 19:00:22 
ID 8 - coffee at 19:00:29 
ID 9 - coffee at 19:00:32 
ID 10 - coffee at 19:00:38 
ID 11 - coffee at 19:00:40
```

Expected Result: Machine A: 4 coffees in 30 seconds Machine B: 6 coffees in 30 seconds because from second 32 to 40 it produced 30 more coffees within 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to display only the records that are less than 30 seconds apart from the first record of a given `machine_id` and `capsule_id` you can use the window function `FIRST_VALUE`. Something like this:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT *,utc_timestamp-FIRST_VALUE(utc_timestamp) OVER w AS calctime
  FROM t
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY machine_id,capsule_id ORDER BY utc_timestamp
               RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
)
SELECT * FROM j
WHERE calctime <= interval '30 seconds'
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5a2669d24b9edb8101fa09eed3083264)

Comment: Hi Jim, I need to show only the records with less than 30 seconds between them, for example machine A has 4 records, 3 of them with less than 30 seconds between them. Machine B has 5 records with 2 of them with less than 30 seconds between them.
I have to compare the first hour of each machine, with the 2nd row onwards to see if there is a difference of 30 seconds.

Comment: @TiagoDezan it wasn't possible to infer this requiremend from your data and description. Could you add more data and the exactly expected results?

Comment: I have a database in which there are several machines that produce coffee, and I have to filter which of these machines in country X produced more than 2 coffees in less than 30 sec. For example:
Machine A
ID 1 - cf 19:00:00
ID 2 - cf 19:00:05
ID 3 - cf 19:00:18
ID 4 - cf 19:00:28
ID 5 - cf 19:00:31
Machine B
ID 6 - cf 19:00:08
ID 7 - cf 19:00:22
ID 8 - cf 19:00:29
ID 9 - cf 19:00:32
ID 10 - cf 19:00:38
ID 11 - cf 19:00:40

Result:
Machine A: 4 coffees in 30 seconds
Machine B: 6 coffees in 30 seconds because from second 32 to 40 it produced 30 more coffees within 30 seconds.

Comment: @TiagoDezan it is extremely hard to read unformatted text in the comments section. Please post it in your answer.. otherwise nobody will be able to read it ;)

Comment: @ Jim done! I edited the question with this comment that I have posted here :)

Comment: @TiagoDezan I'm sorry, but I still cannot read your expected result. Can you list and format it as a table? Doing so we can compare the result of our queries to it. cheers